# Can I set default options for Slurm sbatch?

Tags: linux, configuration-files, slurm

Is it possible for a user to set up a set of default parameters for job submissions? In particular, it would be nice to have all of my jobs give me status updates via email, without having to add this instruction to every job script.

Comment: Have you tried check pointing them ??

Comment: You should simply write your own wrapper script.

Comment: @JohnZwinck That idea sounds promising. Especially if this works with the --wrap option, would you be interested in writing up the answer explicitly? I've actually never written a wrapper script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
OPTS='--mail-type=ALL --mail-user=<address>'
sbatch $OPTS "$@"
```

Thanks to [John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719639/can-i-set-default-options-for-slurm-sbatch#comment74483361_43719639) for the idea.

Comment: For nearly all other options, environment variables can be use to specify job options so you can define them in your bash_profile. See the sbatch manpage

Comment: @damienfrancois Thanks for pointing that out. Do you have an insight as to why the mail options can't be configured using environment variables?

Comment: I cannot think of any technical reason so I would assume it is just missing.

Comment: @damienfrancois I tried adding SBATCH_MAIL_TYPE=ALL and SBATCH_MAIL_USER=<address> to .bashrc, just to see if it was a documentation omission. No email, so that appears not to be the case.

Comment: Someone should expand on this. for example, add a gui interface with checkboxes for each option and a 'create' button (and / or a cli based y or n type of interface) which sets the bash script += to a snippet not unlike the one in this answer. I am looking at you @evan XD . I would do it myself, but I am a noob when it comes to bash.. Definitely nothing to offer on the level of " here you go _programming_ _community._ I wish...